# Undo accidental deletion of Docker image repository

Tags: docker, harbor

I accidentally deleted the wrong repository from Harbor. I read it's now "soft deleted". I wonder if there's a way to bring it back.

Comment: do you know the digest of the repository?

Comment: I'm afraid I have too little experience with Harbor, and I don't know where to find the digest.